# How to create virtualenv with python 3.6 venv

Tags: python, ubuntu

[image]

I'm trying to create a python virtualenv using anaconda python3.6 in ubuntu 16.04. Following https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html , I've tried

```
deploy@server:~/miniconda3/bin$ python3 -m venv ~/test
Error: Command '['/home/deploy/test/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip',    '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

operating from the miniconda directory at ~/miniconda3/bin (screenshot). How can I this working?

edit:

```
deploy@server:~/miniconda3/bin$ /home/deploy/test/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip
/home/deploy/test/bin/python3: No module named ensurepip
```

Comment: Can you run the failing command and post the output? `/home/deploy/test/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip`

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using anaconda, you should be using conda environments.

```
conda create --name test
```

For more information, see [Managing Environments](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html).

---

**EDIT** In response to OP wanting to use virtualenvs.

The error is with python not being able to find `pip`. You can get around this by installing it manually.

```
python3 -m venv test --without-pip
cd test
source bin/activate
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

At this point you will have a basic virtualenv with pip installed.

Comment: Thanks but the use case is more complicated that just this, and has a lot of references to python venvs , so I'd rather use them if possible.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up having to use conda environments anyway.